# IRC server implementation in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, server, chat

People say that the code in my implementation is generally obscure.
Can you point me what looks bad?

```python
import time
import string
from queue import Queue
from channel import Channel
from client import Client


__author__ = 'mark'
import socket
import connection
from threading import Thread

SPECIAL = "[]\`_^{|}"
ALLOWED_NICKNAME = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + SPECIAL + "-"
# noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
ALLOWED_CHANNEL = "".join([chr(x) for x in range(128)]).replace("\0", "").replace("\7", "").replace("\13", "").replace("\10", "")\
    .replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace(":", "")


class IRCServer(object):
    _message_queue = Queue()
    _sock = None
    _connections = None
    _bind_address = None
    running = None
    _clients = None
    _channels = None
    _nick_change_failed = []

    '''
        This prevents memory leak when the client who had error was disconnected
    '''
    def _dead_check_thread(self):
        while self.running:
            for conn in self._nick_change_failed:
                for client_conn in self._clients:
                    if client_conn == conn:
                        break
                else:
                    self._nick_change_failed.remove(conn)

    def _ping_check_thread(self):
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(1.0)
            for conn in self._clients.keys():
                if self._clients[conn].last_pinged >= 250:
                    print("[DBG] %s disconnected because ping has timed-out" %
                          str(conn.address))
                    self.disconnect(conn, "Ping timeout: 250 seconds")
                else:
                    self._clients[conn].last_pinged += 1

    def _ping_thread(self):
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(100.0)
            for client_conn in self._clients.keys():
                try:
                    self._clients[client_conn].send("PING")
                except IOError:
                    self.disconnect(client_conn, "Remote host closed the connection")

    def _message_thread(self):
        while self.running:
            for conn in self._connections:
                try:
                    for msg in conn.get_messages():
                        self._message_queue.put(msg)
                except IOError:  # We couldn't read from socket, thus the connection is dead.
                    print("[DBG] can't read from connection %s" % str(conn))
                    self._connections.remove(conn)

    def _message_handler_thread(self):
        self._nick_change_failed = []
        while self.running:
            msg = self._message_queue.get(True)
            text = msg.get_data()
            conn = msg.get_connection()
            args = text.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").split(" ")
            command = args[0].upper()
            command_args = args[1:]
            if command == "NICK":
                if len(command_args) = 2:
                    self._clients[conn].send("PONG %s" % command_args[1])
                else:
                    self._clients[conn].send("PONG")
            elif command == "QUIT":
                for client in self._clients.values():
                    for channel in self._clients[conn].channels:
                        if channel in client.channels:
                            client.connection.send("%s QUIT %s" % (self._clients[conn].get_identifier(),
                                                                   " ".join(command_args)))
                            break
                del self._clients[conn]  # It's dead
            elif command == "TOPIC":
                if len(command_args)  users and 
               services on  servers"
       252    RPL_LUSEROP
              " :operator(s) online"
       253    RPL_LUSERUNKNOWN
              " :unknown connection(s)"
       254    RPL_LUSERCHANNELS
              " :channels formed"
       255    RPL_LUSERME
              ":I have  clients and 
                servers"
        """
        nick = self._clients[conn].get_nick()
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 251 %s :There are %d users and 0 services on 1 servers" % (self.name, nick, len(self._clients)))
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 252 %s 0 :operator(s) online" % (self.name, nick))
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 253 %s 0 :unknown connection(s)" % (self.name, nick))
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 254 %s %d :channels formed" % (self.name, nick, len(self._channels)))
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 255 %s :I have %d clients and 1 servers" % (self.name, nick, len(self._clients)))

    def _send_no_channel(self, conn, chan_name):
        nick = self._clients[conn].get_nick()
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 403 %s %s :No such channel" % (self.name, nick, chan_name))

    def _send_no_user(self, conn, target):
        nick = self._clients[conn].get_nick()
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 401 %s %s :No such nick/channel" % (self.name, nick, target))

    def _send_not_enough_parameters(self, conn, command):
        nick = self._clients[conn].get_nick()
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 461 %s %s :Not enough parameters" % (self.name, nick, command))

    def _send_unknown_command(self, conn, command):
        nick = self._clients[conn].get_nick()
        self._clients[conn].send(":%s 421 %s %s :Unknown command" % (self.name, nick, command))

    def _send_nickname_in_use(self, conn, nick):
        conn.send(":%s 433 %s :Nickname already in use" % (self.name, nick))

    def _send_erroneous_nickname(self, conn, nick):
        conn.send(":%s 432 %s :Erroneous nickname" % (self.name, nick))

    def disconnect(self, conn, message):
        client = self._clients[conn]
        identifier = client.identifier if client.identifier else client.nick
        self._send_to_related(conn, ":%s QUIT :%s" % (identifier, message))
        try:
            self._clients[conn].send("ERROR :Closing link [%s]: Disconnected" % conn.address)
        except IOError:
            pass
        del self._clients[conn]

    def _send_to_related(self, conn, msg, ignore_self=False):
        clnt = self._clients[conn]
        for client in self._clients.values():
            if ignore_self and client != conn:
                continue

            for channel in client.channels:
                if channel in clnt.channels:
                    client.connection.send(msg)
                    break

    def _channel_broadcast(self, conn, chan, msg):
        for client in self._clients.values():
            if client.nick == self._clients[conn].nick:
                continue
            if chan in client.channels:
                client.send(msg)


    def _nick_in_use(self, nick):
        """
        :param nick: Nickname of client
        :type nick: str
        :return: True if a client with that name exists, else False
        """
        for client in self._clients.values():
            if client.nick == nick:
                return True
        else:
            return False


    def _valid_nick(self, nick):
        if not all(c in ALLOWED_NICKNAME for c in nick) or len(nick) > 9 or\
                not len(nick):
            return False
        return True

    def _set_nick(self, conn, nick, ident=None):
        if self._nick_in_use(nick):
            self._send_nickname_in_use(conn, nick)
            return False
        elif not self._valid_nick(nick):
            self._send_erroneous_nickname(conn, nick)
            return False
        else:
            if not conn in self._clients:
                self._clients[conn] = Client(connection=conn, nick=nick)
            else:
                old_nick = self._clients[conn].nick
                self._clients[conn].nick = nick
                self._send_to_related(conn, "%s NICK %s" % (old_nick, nick))
                if ident:
                    self._clients[conn].ident = self._clients[conn].get_nick() + "!" + \
                                                                   ident + "@" + self.name

            return True


    def __del__(self):
        self._sock.close()
        del self._sock
        self.stop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `IRCServer._ping_check_thread`, you seem to be checking if a client's connection with the server has timed out.

However, you seem to be re-inventing the wheel there. The python socket library already has two functions that handle with timeouts called `socket.setdefaulttimeout` and `socket.settimeout`.

Both of these functions take a float parameter that specifies how long before a the `socket.timeout` error is raised and the user is disconnected. However, the method `socket.setdefaulttimeout` sets the timeout for all sockets.

I recommend that you use this rather than re-invent the wheel.

*Note: I believe by using one of the `settimeout`s, the client will automatically disconnect. However, I don't know for sure.*

---

I may be missing something, but it doesn't look like anywhere in your code are you using the `socket` library.

In that case, I don't see why you `import`ed it.

---

I will look more into this post later; right now, I do not have the time.